# Dynamically add UI Elements in CKEditor Dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to trigger a callback to dynamically populate a CKEditor dialog with checkboxes when the dialog is opened. I've read other solutions that use iframes, but this won't work for me because the dialog needs to be populated based on other elements on the same page.

Here is what I have so far. There are no errors, but the dialog is just empty when it opens. I expect the `addContents` function to fill in the dialog. I've confirmed that `dialog.definition.contents` does include the contents and elements that I want, but it's just not filling in the actual dialog. What am I missing?

```
(function() {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'embeds', {
      icons: 'embed',
      init: function(editor) {
        var self = this,
            elements = [];


        CKEDITOR.dialog.add('EmbedsDialog', function (instance) {
          return {
            title : 'Embeds',
            minWidth : 550,
            minHeight : 200,

            contents: [],

            onShow: function() {
              var dialog = this,
                  elements = [];

              $('#embeds-fields tr').each(function() {
                var title = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val(),
                    url   = $(this).find('input[type=url]').val();

                if(url != "") {
                  elements.push({
                    label : "embed",
                    title : url,
                    type : 'checkbox'
                  });
                }
              });

              dialog.definition.removeContents('embeds');

              dialog.definition.addContents({
                id : 'embeds',
                expand : true,
                elements : elements
              });
            },
          }; // return
        });

        editor.addCommand('Embeds',
          new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('EmbedsDialog', {
            allowedContent: 'a[*](*)'
          })
        );

        editor.ui.addButton('Embeds', {
          label     : 'Embeds',
          command   : 'Embeds',
          toolbar   : 'embeds'
        });
      } // init
    }); // add
})(); // closure
```

Answer (score 4):

Based off of [this example](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/dialog/samples/dialog.html), I ended up with this solution, where "main" is the ID of the original content.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if (dialogName == 'EmbedsDialog') {
    var main = dialogDefinition.getContents('main');

    $('#embeds-fields tr').each(function() {
      var title = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val(),
          url   = $(this).find('input[type=url]').val();

      if(url != "") {
        main.add({
          type : 'checkbox',
          label : title,
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```